# Generating synthetic training examples for support-vector regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, dataset, boosting

Let's say you have a business problem. You want to estimate the demand curve of potato chips based on the percentage of air in the bag, along with a bunch of other features. **You are told at gunpoint that you must use support-vector regression, or decision-tree based regression models.**

You've got data with 1000 training examples, and the percentage of air in the chip bags range from 20% to 40%. You know that sales will be close to or at $0 if the percentage of air in the bag is 100%. You want to make sure the demand curve reflects this.

*Is it fair to generate a few synthetic examples of this by copying a random subset of existing training examples and setting their percentage-of-air values to 100%, and sales to $0?*